# TFS - Latest field still showing "Yes" after deleting local files

Tags: visual-studio, tfs

In TFS Source Control Explorer my items are marked "Yes" in Latest field even though I have deleted all my local files. Is there a way to reevaluate that column so it shows "Not Downloaded" again?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is the solution if you want to delete your files from your local file system (using Windows Explorer for example) and change the column “Latest” in the Source Control Explorer from “Yes” to “Not downloaded”.

Go to “Get Specific Version…” on the files and select Changeset 1.

Changeset 1 is a special changeset on your TFS instance. If you do a get for changeset 1 on any actual files then they will not exist at that point in time on the system so will be deleted locally and the server will know this.

Link with the info: [Removing source control files from your local file system](http://www.woodwardweb.com/tfs_top_tip/tfs_top_tip_11.html)

Answer (score 1):

You should change the scope of your workspace to reflect what you do want locally.

You can also use the Cloak option to prevent sub folders.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181378.aspx#mappings

You should never delete files locally when using a server workspace. If you use a local workspace TFS will lend delete those files from source.

Comment: Why shouldn't I delete it (on server especially) and what are the alternatives when I just want to save some space without getting rid of branches in TFS?

Comment: It's just the way server workspaces work. You need to use the tool to manage the files. If you want control you can switch to a Local workspace.

Answer (score -1):

Source Control Explorer reflects actions you performed to TFS instead of local file system. Please treat them separately. Visual Studio tries to keep them in sync, but it doesn't prevent you from deleting files directly.

Use `tf get <files> /Force` to re-get files you just deleted.

Comment: I don't want to get them - I've had too many branches and I wanted to free some space on my local PC. The problem is after deleting I can't distinguish between downloaded and not donloaded branches.

Comment: Do you really need these branches? If not, just delete them from Source Control Explorer.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm using all of them, however infrequently, so they are necessary.

Comment: You can right click folder and choose Advanced -> Get Specific Version, select Date in type and choose a date before corresponding branch is created. This way, items will be displayed as `Not Downloaded`. However, I don't encourage to do that. Just delete files directly from file system for inactive branches and do a `force get` when you start to work on them.

Comment: You should never delete files outside of the Solution Explorer with Server Workspaces.

Comment: I believe OP already did that. Even TFS treat them as deleted, just don't check in. There is no reason preventing us from deleting files to save disk space.